# How to convert a propositional formula to disjunctive normal form (DNF) in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm new at Prolog, and i need to convert from the truth table the result into disjunctive normal form.
I have been able to produce the truth table as given:

```
?- table(p or(q and not r) or not s or r).
```

```
[p,q,r,s] | (p or (q and not r) or not s or r) ----------------------------------------------|[0,0,0,0] |               1                   |[0,0,0,1] |               0                   |[0,0,1,0] |               1                   |[0,0,1,1] |               1                   |[0,1,0,0] |               1                   |[0,1,0,1] |               1                   |[0,1,1,0] |               1                   |[0,1,1,1] |               1                   |[1,0,0,0] |               1                   |[1,0,0,1] |               1                   |[1,0,1,0] |               1                   |[1,0,1,1] |               1                   |[1,1,0,0] |               1                   |[1,1,0,1] |               1                   |[1,1,1,0] |               1                   |[1,1,1,1] |               1                   |-----------------------------------------------
```

if anyone can help me make from this table to the disjunctive normal form i would apreciate it.

Comment: This is not going to be easy, with all values in your first columns equal to 0.

Comment: Why all rows show [0,0,0,0] ? Your table/1 should show 1/0 under the symbols list.

Answer (score 0):

let's implement a generic truth table evaluator, translating to Prolog evaluable formula in [CDNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_products), then, by [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form), we will disjoin each minterm:

```
:- op(900, fy, neg).
:- op(1000, xfy, and).
:- op(1100, xfy, or).

formula(p or (q and neg r) or neg s or r).

cnf(F, CNF) :-
    setof(V, literal(F, V), Ls),
    setof(La, T^(assign(Ls, La), translate(F, La, T), T), CNF).

literal((X or Y), L) :- literal(X,L) ; literal(Y,L).
literal((X and Y), L) :- literal(X,L) ; literal(Y,L).
literal(neg X, L) :- literal(X,L).
literal(L, L) :- atom(L).

assign(Ls, La) :- maplist(assign_literal, Ls, La).
assign_literal(L, L=true).
assign_literal(L, L=false).

translate((X or Y), Ls, (A;B)) :- translate(X, Ls, A), translate(Y, Ls, B).
translate((X and Y), Ls, (A,B)) :- translate(X, Ls, A), translate(Y, Ls, B).
translate(neg X, Ls, \+ A) :- translate(X, Ls, A).
translate(L, Ls, V) :- memberchk(L=V, Ls).
```

yields:

```
?- formula(F),cnf(F,CNF),maplist(writeln,CNF).
[p=false,q=false,r=false,s=false]
[p=false,q=false,r=true,s=false]
[p=false,q=false,r=true,s=true]
[p=false,q=true,r=false,s=false]
[p=false,q=true,r=false,s=true]
[p=false,q=true,r=true,s=false]
[p=false,q=true,r=true,s=true]
[p=true,q=false,r=false,s=false]
[p=true,q=false,r=false,s=true]
[p=true,q=false,r=true,s=false]
[p=true,q=false,r=true,s=true]
[p=true,q=true,r=false,s=false]
[p=true,q=true,r=false,s=true]
[p=true,q=true,r=true,s=false]
[p=true,q=true,r=true,s=true]
F = or(p, or(and(q, neg(r)), or(neg(s), r))),
CNF = [[p=false, q=false, r=false, s=false], [p=false, q=false, r=true, s=false], [p=false, q=false, r=true, s=true], [p=false, q=true, r=false, s=false], [p=false, q=true, r=false, ... = ...], [p=false, q=true, ... = ...|...], [p=false, ... = ...|...], [... = ...|...], [...|...]|...].
```

Sorry the output it's a bit verbose. Can be easily tailored on further spec.

I used neg/1 instead of [not](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=not/1)/1 (that's already a valid Prolog operator), just to make clear the distinction...

*Edit*

Here is a simplification, resulting in a syntactic generalization. Just literal/2 and translate/3 have changed, and translate/2 has been added:

```
literal(F, L) :- F =.. [_,X,Y], (literal(X,L) ; literal(Y,L)).
literal(F, L) :- F =.. [_,X], literal(X,L).
literal(L, L) :- atom(L).

translate(and, (,)).
translate(or, (;)).
translate(neg, (\+)).

translate(F, Ls, T) :-
    F =.. [S,X,Y],
    translate(S,O),
    T =.. [O,A,B],
    translate(X, Ls, A), translate(Y, Ls, B).
translate(F, Ls, T) :-
    F =.. [S,X],
    translate(S,O),
    T =.. [O,A],
    translate(X, Ls, A).
translate(F, Ls, T) :- memberchk(F=T, Ls).
```

**More Edit**

The code above can be made more efficient, just moving the translation out of the cycle

```
cnf(F, CNF) :-
    setof(V, literal(F, V), Ls),
    translate(F, La, T),
    setof(La, (assign(Ls, La), T), CNF).
```

a minor modification is required in last translate/3 clause: use member/2 instead of memberchk

```
...
translate(F, Ls, T) :- member(F=T, Ls).
```

Timing: with the old version

```
4 ?- formula(F),time(cnf(F,CNF)).
% 1,788 inferences, 0.002 CPU in 0.002 seconds (98% CPU, 834727 Lips)
```

With the new one:

```
5 ?- formula(F),time(cnf(F,CNF)).
% 282 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (99% CPU, 315768 Lips)
```

about 6x better.

Old with memberchk:

```
6 ?- formula(F),time(cnf(F,CNF)).
% 1,083 inferences, 0.002 CPU in 0.002 seconds (98% CPU, 561426 Lips)
```

Well, still almost 4x better.

**Edit** Some more step is required to get a true Prolog formula

```
cdnf(F, CNDF, Prolog) :-
    cdnf(F, CNDF),  % well, was cnf/2, I renamed to be more precise
    maplist(cj, CNDF, CJs),
    reverse(CJs, [H|T]),
    foldl(dj, T, H, Prolog).

dj(A, B, (A;B)).

cj(A, J) :-
    maplist(tf, A, B),
    reverse(B, [H|T]),
    foldl(cj, T, H, J).
cj(A, B, (A,B)).

tf(S=true,S).
tf(S=false,\+S).
```

now, the result is more usable

```
?- formula(_,F), cdnf(F,_,P).
F = or(p, or(and(q, neg(r)), or(neg(s), r))),
P = (\+p, \+q, \+r, \+s;\+p, \+q, r, \+s;\+p, \+q, r, s;\+p, q, \+r, \+s;\+p, q, \+r, s;\+p, q, r, \+ ...;\+p, q, ..., ...;p, ..., ...;..., ...;...;...)
```